# Malloc and free in double recursion

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, free

I was playing with C code when i encountered the following problem. I have a code that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a {
  int n1;
  int n2;
} el;

typedef struct list {
  el *elements;
  int nElements;
} list;

void copyList(list in, list *out) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < in.nElements; i++) {
        out->elements = realloc(out->elements,sizeof(el)*(out->nElements + 1));
        out->elements[i] = in.elements[i];
        out->nElements = out->nElements + 1;
    }
}

void initList(list *l) {
    l->nElements = 0;
    l->elements = NULL;
}

void freeList(list *l) {
    l->nElements = 0;
    if(l->elements != NULL) {
        free(l->elements);
        l->elements = NULL;
    }
}

void testRecur(int i, list l) {
    list l1;

    if(i > 0) {
        initList(&l1);
        copyList(l,&l1);
        // freeList(&l);
        testRecur(i-1,l1);
        testRecur(i-2,l1);
        // freeList(&l1);
    }
    else {
        // freeList(&l);
    }

}

int main(void) {
  list l1;
  list l2;
  el element;

  initList(&l1);
  initList(&l2);

  l1.elements = malloc(sizeof(el)*2);
  l1.nElements = 2;

  element.n1 = 1;
  element.n2 = 2;
  l1.elements[0] = element;

  element.n1 = 3;
  element.n2 = 4;
  l1.elements[1] = element;

  testRecur(10,l1);

  // freeList(&l1);

  return 0;
}
```

It is a simple code that copies recursively a list a certain number of times. It has no sense but it is easy enough to explain the concept. The problem is: where should i place the `free` calls? I've tried all the combinations of the commented spots but i end up having a double free error (`*** Error in ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001ecd010 ***`) or a memory leak detection with `valgrind` (with the following arguments: `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./a.out`). Is there a way to not leak memory (at least according to valgrind)?

Comment: `free(&l1);` --> `free(l1.elements);`

Comment: You free the same thing you assign the `malloc` result to.

Comment: regarding: `out->elements = realloc(out->elements,sizeof(el)*(out->nElements + 1));`  when calling `realloc()`, which can fail.  save the returned pointer in a 'temp' pointer check (!=NULL) and only if not NULL, assign that pointer to the target variable. `out->elements`  If ==NULL, then call `perror( "realloc failed" );`  Note once `realloc()` fails, it will (probably) continue to fail. So suggest 'cleaning up' and calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove all occurences of *freeList(&l);* from *testRecur()* function.

**Explanation:**

A good practice while using alloc(and its variants) and free is to try to do both in same scope. In your example, the functions which are allocating memories to list are in *main()* and *copyList()*.

1.***main()*** function allocation and de-allocation can be done in same scope easily:

```
int main(void) {
  /*
   Initialization code
  */
  // Allocation
  l1.elements = malloc(sizeof(el)*2);
  l1.nElements = 2;
  /*
   Process list l1, but dont play with its memory.
   A thumb rule can be to pass l1(by reference) as const
  */

  // De-allocation
  freeList(&l1);

  return 0;
}
```

2.***copyList()***: As per code, we cant free list in *copyList* itself as we need it later. So we do the next best thing - de-allocate in the function which called *copyList*. Think of *copyList* having two parts - allocation and copying.

```
void testRecur(int i, list l) {
    list l1;

    if(i > 0) {
        initList(&l1);
        /* memory will be allocated in copyList. 
           So, allocation scope starts here */
        copyList(l, &l1);
        /* Process list l1, but again, dont play with its memory */
        testRecur(i-1,l1);
        testRecur(i-2,l1);
        /* Now l1 is no more required, its scope is finished.
           We can free l1. */
        freeList(&l1);
    }
}
```

Note: This is not related to allocate and free, but passing structure(list) as value is of no significance in your example, so its better to pass list by reference in function *testRecur().*

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
void testRecur(int i, list l) {
    list l1;

    if(i > 0) {
        initList(&l1);
        copyList(l,&l1);
```

the call to `copyList()` places the result of a call to `realloc()` in the local variable `l1`  However, those `realloc()`d memory are never passed to `free()`

Suggest:

```
void testRecur(int i, list l) 
{
    list l1;

    if( i > 0 )
    {
        initList(&l1);
        copyList(l,&l1);
        testRecur(i-1,l);
        freeList(&l1);
    }
}
```

Then the local variable allocated memory would be free'd as the recursion unwound the stack.

However, this would result in the second parameter to the function never being free'd.  so the `main()` function would still need to `free()` that parameter